# Meaning of def(_f) and del(_f) at the beginning of ABC collections

Tags: python-3.x, abc

Just went across internals of [ABC collections](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/_collections_abc.py).

Can anyone please explain what does this construct stand for:

```
def _f(): pass
FunctionType = type(_f)
del _f
```

I know I'm probably missing some basic concept(s), please advise where to start/look to understand this?

Comment: `FunctionType` is supposed to represent the type that functions are. The easiest way for python to record what type a function is, is to create one, _check_ what type it is, and then delete it so that it's not polluting the namespace.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Any idea why it doesn't do `FunctionType = type(lambda: None)` instead?

Comment: Presumably because, at some point in the feature, lambdas may become a meaningfully different type than functions, and in that case they'd want to put that in a separate type variable `LambdaType` instead.